# How to get General Link Field in RenderFieldArgs?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have made a custom processor to add custom code to General Link Field and Rich Text Field.

But in the **(RenderFieldArgs args)** I am only getting rich text field, the General Link Field is not coming. The config is correct as the Rich text field is coming but General Link Field and other fields are missing.

```
public class CustomExpandLinks
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));


            if (Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
                return;

            args.Result.FirstPart = ExpandUrlsInCustomWay(args.Result.FirstPart, UrlOptions.DefaultOptions);
            args.Result.LastPart = ExpandUrlsInCustomWay(args.Result.LastPart, UrlOptions.DefaultOptions);
```

Please help what I am missing in this to get the **General Link** field

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, you don't want to mess with the pipelines and you want to create a custom link provider instead? https://gist.github.com/Adamsimsy/4c4af66a53d3b7ba2ebef5a46c067ca7

Comment: No I want to use this only as it is working for my Rich Text field. Please provide a solution for this. @Marek Musielak

Comment: I provided you already in your previous question. It's all there. Debug the code, see what it does

Comment: It is working fine for the Rich Text field but I am not getting General Link field in the Args that is the problem. @Marek Musielak

Comment: Please help me, I am using Sitecore 9.3 @MarekMusielak

Comment: @GautamAneja - did you manage to sort this out by any chance?